# Computing the standard deviation of the momentum operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I have a wave function as follows:

$$
\psi = A_o \mathrm e^{-\alpha x^2}
$$

And I want to compute the standard deviation of the momentum operator:

$$
\Delta p = \sqrt{\langle p^2\rangle-\langle p\rangle^2}
$$

I think I might be getting something wrong because when I compute the integrals I get: $\langle p\rangle=0$ and $\langle p^2\rangle$ negative, which means that $\Delta p \not \in \mathbb{R}$, does that make any sense? or the standard deviation of the momentum has to be real?

Note:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2\mathrm e^{-\alpha x²} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4a^{3/2}}
$$

Comment: How are you getting $\langle p^2 \rangle$ negative? The usual intuition about squares being positive is still true in this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calculating the expectation value of $p^2$? Remember $p = -i \hbar \partial_x$, so $p^2 = - \hbar^2 \partial^2$; that minus sign is vital! $\langle p^2 \rangle$ is then equal to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi^{\ast}(x) \left(- \partial_x^2 \psi(x) \right) dx$ which should give a positive result.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x e^{-2\alpha x^2}$ is odd and 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,x e^{-2\alpha x^2}$ exists, this integral will be $0$.  By the same argument $x^2 e^{-2\alpha x^2}$ is even so it is not possible for this integral to be $0$ since the area under the curve of a non-negative function must be non-zero.   Note the bounds in the integral, which differ from those you have written in your normalization condition.